# What is wrong with my login in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

Im a Laravel noob, I have a question regarding my Laravel code. It registers successfully, and saves the web session when registering, but not when logging in. It works fine with the login, when I entered a wrong password on purpose, the correct action is happenning, and also when I log in correctly. But When I log in, it doesnt save the session at all, its empty. Please take a look:

My UserController function for logging in:

```
public function processLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password'] ], true))
    {
        Auth::login(Auth::user());

        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->back();
    }


}
```

and my routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', function () {

        print_r(Session::all());

        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            print_r($user);
        } else {
            echo 'Guest';
        }


        return view('welcome');
    });



Route::prefix('welcome')->group(function () {
    Route::get('about', 'WelcomeController@about');

    Route::get('features', 'WelcomeController@features');

    Route::get('pricing', 'WelcomeController@pricing');

    Route::get('help', 'WelcomeController@help');
});

Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', 'UserController@login');
    Route::post('login', 'UserController@processLogin');

    Route::get('register', 'UserController@register');
    Route::post('register', 'UserController@processRegister');

    Route::get('logout', 'UserController@processLogout');
});    
});





Auth::routes();
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/17

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should empty you users table and try this command :

```
php artisan make:auth
```

It`s work for me .